# .Net Serialization

Tags: c#-3.0

Isn't `OnDeserialized` redundant with `IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the documentation on the [OnDeserialized attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx) and the [IDeserializationCallback interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback.aspx), you'll see that that interface was first implemented in .NET 1.0, while the attribute was added in .NET 2.0, along with a number of additional related attributes that provide more fine-grained control of the serialization / deserialization process.

From the OnDeserializedAttribute remarks section:

> This attribute can be used instead of
>   the IDeserializationCallback
>   interface.

So to answer your question, yes, they are redundant. An educated guess would be that the attribute-based markers are the preferred way to do this, as they give you more flexibility and do not require a separate interface to use. The interface is there because if they removed it, it would break backwards compatibility with older code.